# How to pass data from parent view's presenter to child view's presenter?

Tags: android, mvp

I am using MVP patterns in Android. And structure looks like below.

```
Activity - Presenter
    |
Fragment
    |
CustomView
    |
  views
```

So when the presenter gets data from the network, it directly passes data to fragment, and fragment pass data to a custom view and custom view pass data to views.

I am not sure how I can pass data used in views from activity with MVP patterns. If I make presenters for each fragments, custom views, and views, then how can I pass data from activity's presenter to other presenters?
Anyone can help me out with examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to give a more specific answer to your question you need to give a concrete example. Every solution is valid in a ***context***. I'll give couple of ways you can do this. Choose the one that suits your problem.

Very important part of the ***MVP*** is the ***Model***. As far as I'm aware the term ***Model*** became popular in programing with the release of the paper [Thing Model View Editor](https://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/1979/mvc-1/1979-05-MVC.pdf) which was later refined and renamed to MVC.

The definition of the concept of a ***Model*** from this paper is:

> A ***Model*** is an active representation of an ***abstraction*** in the form of
>   data in a computing system
>
> The ***Models*** are represented in the computer as a collection of *data*
>   *together with the methods* necessary to process these data.

With time and experience, people have discovered and specified different types of models.

Here are some of them:

- [Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)
- Application Model *(read [this article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) for more information)*
- [Presentation Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html)

**MVP**, since it derives from MVC, makes two major divisions of responsibilities: ***Model*** (*the abstraction that represent concepts*) and ***Presentation*** (*View and Presenter* to visualize the ***Model***).

Because we have divided the ***Model*** from the ***Presentation***, we can have multipe ***Views*** that show the same ***Model*** different ways. An example of that is a ***Model*** that represents ***Statistical Data*** that can be shown different ways: a Pie chart, a Bar chart etc. In this example the ***Statistical Data Model*** is a ***Domain Model***.

In the example above, the ***Model*** will probably be shared between the two ***View-Presenter pairs*** , The ***PieChart*** and the ***BarChart***. If you use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), when one of the ***View-Presenter pairs*** update the ***StatisticalModel***, it will raise changed events, and both ***View-Presenter pairs*** will receive notifications for this change and update.

Sometimes an application needs an ***ApplicationModel***. This model can be shared between different ***View-Presentation pairs***. Let's take a look at a *verfy simplified* example.

Let's say we have a File Browser application like Windows Explorer. This GUI of the application has two major parts: The left panel that shows a *Tree* of the folders and the middle File-Folder panel. When a folder is selected in the left folders tree panel, files and folders from the selected folder must be shown in the middle panel. We can do this by defining an ***ApplicationModel*** that will capture and represent the above logic and be shared between both ***View-Presentation pairs*** for the left and middle panels.

*Note: I'll omit details to simply the example and write less code*

```
public class ApplicationState {

    // singleton, it's evil I know, 
    // but it's the simplest way without DI or ServiceLocator
    private static ApplicationState mInstance = new ApplicationState();
    public static ApplicationState getInstance() { return mInstance; }

    private Folder mSelectedFolder;

    public bool hasSelectedFolder() { return mSelectedFolder != null; }

    public Folder getSelectedFolder() { return mSelectedFolder; }

    public Folder setSelectedFolder(Folder f) {
        mSelectedFolder = f;
        RaiseSelectedFolderChangedEvent();
    }

    // method for registering listeners, raising events etc.
}

public class FoldersTreeViewPresenter {

    private ApplicationState mApplicationState;

    public void onSelectFolder(FolderView view) {
        // select the folder in the view
        mApplicationState.setSelectedFolder(view.Folder);
    }
}

public class FilesFoldersViewPresenter : ApplicationStateListener {

    private ApplicationState mApplicationState;

    public FilesFoldersViewPresenter() {

        // you can use service locator, dependency injection, whatever
        mApplicationState = ApplicationState.getInstance();

        mApplicationState.addEventListener(this);
    }

    private void getFilesAndFoldersFromFileSystem(Folder folder) {
        // get from fs
        // fill views with them etc.
    }

    private void clearView() { 
        // clear the panel
    }

    public void onApplicationStateChanged() {

        if(mApplicationState.hasSelectedFolder()){
            getFilesAndFoldersFromFileSystem(mApplicationState.getSelectedFolder());
        }
        else {
            clearView();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we created a shared object that represent the application state and the logic, that our application has a selection that can be changed. In this case the ***ApplicationState*** class is part of the ***Model*** and is an ***Application Model***. Because it is shared and it's life time is the same as the application (it exists as long as the application is running) it will hold the state. ***Views*** and ***Presenters*** are created and destroyed, but this class will exist and hold the state, so that when a new ***View*** and/or ***Presenter*** is created it can check this state and do something.

In my experince people do concentrate on Views and Presenters more, while they should work on their ***Models***. Peronally I use ***Models*** alot as it makes things cleaner and the application easier to understand.

Of course, using ***Models*** doesn't always work, so when they don't you can use ***messaging***, having one ***Presenter*** sending messages to others. Here's an example with the same File Browser app.

```
public class MessageBus {
    // static this time, you can use DI or ServiceLocator with interface
    public static void sendMessage(object m) { }
    public static void registerListener(MessageListener listener) { }
}

public class FoldersTreeViewPresenter {

    public void onSelectFolder(FolderView view) {
        // select the folder in the view
        MessageBus.sendMessage(new FolderSelected(view.Folder));
    }
}

public class FilesFoldersViewPresenter : MessageListener {

    public FilesFoldersViewPresenter() {
        MessageBus.addListener(this);
    }

    private void getFilesAndFoldersFromFileSystem(Folder folder) {
        // get from fs
        // fill views with them etc.
    }

    public void onMessage(object m) {

       if(m instanceof FolderSelected) {

            FolderSelected folderSelectedMessage = (FolderSelected)m;

            getFilesAndFoldersFromFileSystem(folderSelectedMessage.Folder);
       }
    }
}
```

Depending on your specific case, if you can create a nice ***Model***, either a Domain, Application or Presentation, do it. Share this ***Model*** thus creating a dependency on the ***Model*** from the ***Presenters*** instead of creating a dependency *between* ***Presenters***. This way you have loose coupling between ***Presenters*** and you can change them much easier

If you can't use a ***Model***, use a ***Messages***. It's a nice way to decouple ***Presenters*** by creating a ***protocol*** of messages that are used for communication.

Check [this](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventCollaboration.html) article on using messages for collaboration between components.

Also here are some good articles on GUI architectures:

- https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html
- http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2007/08/25/interactive-application-architecture/